AES256 encrypt & decrypt in C# returns inconsistent length byte[]
When encrypting and decrypting a byte[] in C# (using the code below), the final byte array's length is (sometimes) incorrect.
I found the following pattern:

when the input array's length is less than or equal to 16, the result array has the correct length (inputBytes.Length <= 16) // works correctly
when it's more than 16, the result is only the first 16 bytes of the input array (inputBytes.Length > 16) // output limited to first 16 bytes
after that, the output is limited to 16 bytes until we reach 32 or more input bytes. Then it limits the output length to 32
I suppose the same happens at 48, 64, etc bytes too, but I haven't tested that yet

        public static byte[] EncryptBytesUsingKey(byte[] data, byte[] key) // encrypt, key size should be 32!!
        {
            using Aes aes256 = BuildAesWithKey(key);
            aes256.GenerateIV();
            using ICryptoTransform encryptorTransform = aes256.CreateEncryptor();
            using MemoryStream memStreamEnc = new();
            using CryptoStream cryptStreamEnc = new(memStreamEnc, encryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            memStreamEnc.Write(aes256.IV, 0, aes256.IV.Length);
            cryptStreamEnc.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptStreamEnc.FlushFinalBlock();
            return memStreamEnc.ToArray();
        }

        public static byte[] DecryptBytesUsingKey(byte[] data, byte[] key) // decrypt, key size should be 32!
        {
            using Aes aes256 = BuildAesWithKey(key);
            aes256.IV = data.Take(16).ToArray(); // IV len 16, so just take 16 and skip 16
            byte[] encData = data.Skip(16).ToArray();
            using ICryptoTransform decryptorTrasnform = aes256.CreateDecryptor();
            using MemoryStream memStreamDec = new(encData);
            using CryptoStream cryptStreamDec = new(memStreamDec, decryptorTrasnform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] result = new byte[encData.Length];
            int bytesRead = cryptStreamDec.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
            return result.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();
        }

        static Aes BuildAesWithKey(byte[] key)
        {
            Aes aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Key = key;
            return aes;
        }

Additional info:

the key is currently a random SHA256 hash
this is how I tested the functions (simplified): Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DecryptBytesUsingKey(EncryptBytesUsingKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test string"), hash), hash));
trying all padding modes (System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode. ) didn't fix the issue
I already tried the 'forbidden fruit' (asked AIs), but with no success

I really appreciate any kind of help in advance!!

Works on .NET 5.0, but not as of .NET 6.0! Caused by a breaking change in .NET 6.0. Possible fix via CopyTo(), see https://dotnetfiddle.net/nmDP9P
